# TypeScript error : Type '.....' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Number'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Newbie to TypeScript I try to port a JS code to TS and I get the error

```
[ts]
Type '{ current: number; total: number; }' is not assignable to type 
'IntrinsicAttributes & Number'.
  Type '{ current: number; total: number; }' is not assignable to type 
'Number'.
Property 'toFixed' is missing in type '{ current: number; total: number; }'.
(JSX attribute) current: number
```

The function

```
function Header(current: number, total: number, question: DEEP_QUESTION){
//  console.log("Header " + current.toString());
  return (
      <div> 
        <StepBar current={current} total={total} />
        <SurveyTheme theme={question.theme} />
      </div>
  )
  //refresh();
}
```

The messages appears on the StepBar call parameters.
The signature of StepBar

```
function StepBar(current: number, total: number) {
```

This works in JS

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

StepBar should accept a props object with members as current and total.

Can you try using something like :

```
function StepBar(props: {current: number, total: number}) { ... }
```

Comment: It seems to resolve the problem
Crazy language !
thanks !

Comment: Since it's working in JS, it's an issue in the React type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.StatelessComponent` generic to pass your prop types as follows:

```
interface IHeaderProps {
    current: number;
    total: number;
 }

const Header:React.StatelessComponent<IHeaderProps> =  (props) => {
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```